# How to reassign STI class to a variable within model's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I've got STI like this:

```
class Post
end

class Post::Confirmed < Post
end

class Post::Draft < Post
  def confirm!
    becomes Post::Confirmed
  end
end

...# somewhere in controller
# POST /posts/1/confirm
# POST /posts/1/confirm.json
def confirm
  @post = Post::Draft.first
  @post = @post.confirm!    # this is the only way I can reload @post with Post::Confrmed 
end
```

Is it somehow possible to make:

```
@post.confirm! # I want this @post(Post::Draft) to become Post::Confirmed without reassigning
```

Or is it just nor RoR way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that STI is appropriate in this case? Wouldn't a simple status flag and some scopes make more sense?

Comment: I've though about that, but the scope is a little bigger then in this example: all subclasses works as namespaces for given classes, so drafts have their own methods and confirmed posts — their own. 
I guess, I can be wrong. But still, STI looks perfect for that.

Comment: @muistooshort imagine, that you've got shopping cart. It's structurally the same as the Order: it's got items, total price etc. But the methods for each of class are different.

Comment: Switching an object's type is probably a really bad idea and ActiveRecord makes it difficult on purpose. Just flip a flag. Your shopping cart example makes more sense, certain kinds of line-items would have different properties than others, but transmogrifying one into another is really bizarre.

Comment: @tadman I've just wanted to know if there's any better way to deal with that instead of reassigning the variable each time. But if it's not possible — whatever, I an deal with that, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I've found that works best here is having a `datetime` type field that records when the record was flagged.

For example:

```
def confirm!
  self.confirmed_at = DateTime.now
  self.save!
end
```

Then you can tell *when* something was confirmed. This comes in especially handy for when you have a situation where something *will* be flagged but isn't yet, such as setting a publishing date in the future.

Although it might seem a little annoying to not have your STI bag of tricks available, STI is not always the appropriate tool. Generally STI is to differentiate between similar but different models that have a lot of commonality or are used in a common context. It's not supposed to be used to handle different states of a singular model.

What you want in that case is a state-machine type pattern.

Comment: actually, true, but state-machine gems are awful: statesman is too complicated to use, and state_machine is not maintained for a year..
all I wanted to use "bang" method, that will change the instance (as all bang-methods do). But if it's not possible, I'll stick with the reassigning the variable. For me this way is more clear and robust. Thanks for your answer though)

Comment: I've just found another gem, that looks promising actually: aasm

Comment: The reason state-machine type gems are not always well maintained is because implementing that behaviour yourself is trivial. Give it a shot.